# mongoose schema set max length for a String

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, schema

I'm doing a schema with mongoose in Nodejs. And I'm trying to find a way to limit the number of character in a [SchemaString](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema-string-js). I found that it is possible to use a regex with the keyword *match* like :

```
var schema = new Schema({
{
    name: {type: String, match: '/^.{0,20}$/'}
});
```

But I just want to know if there is some parameter to directly specify a *maximum length*, like this :

```
var schema = new Schema({
{
    name: {type: String, max: 20}
});
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `maxlength` should be in the [Mongoose release 4.0.0-rc2](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/commit/b96d72440769a4fc038e3934b268b1ec648dd16d)

Comment: Why not do the limitations on the input instead of on the server? This would be much easier... I think?

Comment: min and max work https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Since Mongoose [4.0.0-rc2](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/commit/b96d72440769a4fc038e3934b268b1ec648dd16d)**, the [`maxLength`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#string-validators) validation is available:

```js
var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true, maxLength: 20}
});
```

---

For versions **older than 4.0.0-rc2**, there [is no such validation](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1457) built in.

You can however create this validation using path function:

```
Schema.path('name').validate(function (v) {
    return v.length <= 20;
}, 'The maximum length is 20.');
```

Or you can use [mongoose-validator](https://github.com/leepowellcouk/mongoose-validator). From the example in their README:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var validate = require('mongoose-validator');

var nameValidator = [
  validate({
    validator: 'isLength',
    arguments: [3, 50],
    message: 'Name should be between 3 and 50 characters'
  }),
  validate({
    validator: 'isAlphanumeric',
    passIfEmpty: true,
    message: 'Name should contain alpha-numeric characters only'
  })
];

var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true, validate: nameValidator}
});
```

Comment: btw there's length validation now: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html e.g. name: {type: String, maxlength: 100}

Comment: for first approach, how to add error message